Multi-task learning- Loss function
I am training a convolutional autoencoder with two velocity fields as inputs and outputs. These fields represent wind velocities in both the x and y directions within a square domain. My loss function is defined as Loss = Loss1 + w * Loss2
Loss1 = MSE between targets and outputs.
Loss2 = MSE between the derivatives of U and V (components of velocity) in the target data and the derivatives in the outputs. I used the Sobel filter to calculate derivatives.
I have  two questions:
Q1) I noticed that when I train the model using only Loss1, the results are better compared to training with both Loss1 and Loss2. I initially expected that incorporating Loss2 would act as regularization and improve generalization. What could be the reason for this outcome?
Q2) Is it acceptable to calculate Loss1 using normalized data and Loss2 using actual (unnormalized) data? Or should both losses be computed using the same type of data?

please make sure to read [ask] page
